# Equivalent of IO.inspect function that just returns string instead of printing given list, map or keyword list?

Tags: elixir

Elixir newbie here. I've been trying to convert KeywordList into a string. I can do so with

```
IO.inspect([name: "John Doe"])
```

but it prints the string to console. Is there a function that just returns the string?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
inspect([name: "John Doe"])
```

It is defined by the Kernel module and therefore automatically imported.

Comment: Note though that, IINM, `IO.inspect` pretty prints by default. And by default `Kernel.inspect` does not. So to get the equivalent of `IO.inspect` at the terminal you'd need `IO.puts(inspect(<thing>, pretty: true))`. Also in both cases pretty printing only kicks in once the resulting string is over 80 chars, if you want smaller inspections to be pretty too you pass `, width: 0` after `pretty: true`.